# Pacote Survey e contagem

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com a base de dados do IBGE - PNAD com ajuda do pacote Survey. Para fazer uma contagem de respostas (por exemplo, proporção de pessoas com idade menor que 15 anos na região norte) é necessário usar esse pacote? nesse caso qual seria o comando?

Comment: você deve utilizar o pacote survey não pelo pacote em si, mas como um meio de incluir o plano amostral na análise. Você deve fazer isso pois devido ao procedimento amostral da PNAD os indivíduos tem pesos diferentes. Acho que sua dúvida, e ainda outras que puder ter, podem ser sanadas no seguinte livro:http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470284307.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário usar o survey, principalmente para procedimentos mais simples. No caso, um simples `aggregate()` já seria suficiente para ti. Não tenho os dados da PNAD no meu computador agora, mas segue um exemplo:

```
library(survey)
dados <- data.frame(Peso = rchisq(100, 10), Idade = rnorm(100, 40, 10))

delineamento <- svydesign(ids = ~ 1, weights = ~ Peso, data = dados)
svytable(~ Idade > 30, delineamento)

aggregate(Peso ~ Idade > 30, dados, FUN = sum)
```

Note que os 2 resultados são iguais. Importante ressaltar que um simples `table()` não serve pois cada observação possui peso diferente.

```
with(dados, table(Idade > 30))
```

Escrevi [uma postagem sobre o survey num blog](http://www.dadosaleatorios.com.br/2014/06/trabalhando-com-amostras-complexas-no-r.html), talvez lhe seja útil (em especial os links nos comentários).

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço o pacote `survey`, mas gosto de me ater às funções base do R para resolver qualquer problema antes de recorrer a um pacote extra.

Já que você não disponibilizou dados como exemplo, usarei a base embutida `mtcars`

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Para saber quantos casos há para cada valor, basta usar a função `table`. Lembre-se que se fala em contagem/frequência apenas com variáveis discretas ou categóricas:

```
> table(mtcars$gear)

 3  4  5 
15 12  5
```

Ou seja, há 15 casos com `gear == 3`, 12 com `gear == 4` e 5 com `gear == 5`. O mesmo pode ser feito "cruzando variáveis":

```
> table(mtcars$carb , mtcars$gear)

    3 4 5
  1 3 4 0
  2 4 4 2
  3 3 0 0
  4 5 4 1
  6 0 0 1
  8 0 0 1
```